# Confused about Javascript Hoisting

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, hoisting

```
function a(){
  function b(){
  }
}
```

In the above code of javascript, during the hoisting phase, will the function `b` be hoisted? Or just `a` will be hoisted because only function `a` is sitting lexically in the global context.

Comment: Hoisting always happens *per scope*. `b` is hoisted, but only inside the function scope, whenever `a()` is called.

Comment: which means `b` will not be hoisted if we don't call `a()`?

Comment: It means there will be no `b` if you don't call `a()`, and there will be as many `b`s as you call it multiple times. For `b`, you must only consider the scope `… { function b(){} } …` it lives in (which is the `a` function body) and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` will be hosted to the top of the scope it appears in (the scope defined by the body of function `a`) during the hoisting phase when that function (`a`) is invoked.

`b` will not be exported to the global scope.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a really clear illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Function a will be hoisted to top of global scope (assuming this in the global scope) and function b will be hoisted to the top of the scope created by function a.

Answer (score -1):

Declarations are hoisted to the top of their containing scope, which for function `b` is function `a`.

Function `b` will be hoisted to the top of function `a`, but that is where it already is.

And, function `a` (based on your code) will be hoisted to the top of the Global scope.

Answer (score -1):

In hoisting process all the declarations will move up below the parent function declaration.

```
Ex: function fun(){
    a = 10;
    var c = b();
    function b(){}
}
```

will become like

```
function fun(){
 var a;
 var c;
 function b(){};
 a = 10;
 c = b();
}
```